# Alternatives to excel addin "morefunc" at 64bit

Tags: excel, excel-addins

I've a lot of documents in excel that using the morefunc's formulas (done with my excel 32bit).

Today i've discovered that there are no other version of this addin. Has the developer abandoned the development?
Unfortunatly this addin works only with 32bit  version of excel

What can we do to use our documents in a machine that has installed 64bit version of Office?
There is an alternative for this addin? Something that defined the same functions with the same parameters..

Comment: unfortunately this type of recommendation question is offtopic accross the stackexchange network. You will have to ask it on a non-SE site. Or try alternativeto.net.

Comment: ok, thanks.
How can i change my question to be on-topic?

Comment: you can't. You have to ask it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just install a 32-bit version of Excel? Maybe in a virtual machine or VDI (Virtual desktop infrastructure), if you have troubles installing it on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

While this will require adding macros to your documents, you might want to use VBA to emulate Morefunc's functions. All of them have VBA alternatives.